# Words similar to "vainly"/"in vain" meaning it is pointless to even try do do something

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm reading a poem which contains the lines "How vainly men themselves amaze / to win the palm, the oak, the bays". This got me wondering about words like "vainly" or "in vain" not meaning:

"doing something to no avail"

but:

"there being no point in even attempting something because it couldn't possibly produce the desired outcome"

Is the second one actually a different meaning or is it just a question of context? Are there any words which mean specifically the second? All I can think of right now is "pointlessly".

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vainly

Answer (score 2):

[*Avail*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/avail): use, benefit, or advantage. To no avail would be, then, to no use, benefit, or advantage. Nothing useful came out of the attempt; it was unsuccessful. It is similar, then, to *futile*.

How do you know something is in vain *unless you've tried*? Futile and vainly connote an attempt:

> All his *efforts* were in vain; *resistance* was futile.

In your second 'definition', you are assuming the chances are so remote one doesn't even try. That is not in vain or futile. That is *impossible*, in which case *attempting something would be foolish*. As in the following (**vainly is misused**):

> His vainly attempted to walk across the Pacific Ocean.

A good dictionary should give you the denotation (exact definition) of a word, as well as, somewhere among the synonyms, the **connotation** of a word. The latter is where the subtlety and elegance of words lie.

Synonyms for pointless or impossible:

> senseless, meaningless, stupid, silly, useless, absurd, irrelevant, worthless, nonsensical, inane, without rhyme or reason.

Edited to add: I read the poem *The Garden*. It is about the contrasted virtues of the active and the contemplative life. The last couplet (which became a standard sundial inscription) is "*How could such sweet and wholsome Hours / Be reckon'd but with herbs and flow'rs!*"

As the *active life* is being criticized, it is in the sense of men not finding contentment except in 'the Garden' (originally that of Eden). Vainly men seek contentment in worldly pursuits. That is not *proudly* but **unsuccessfully**.

Answer (score 0):

In the poem, I feel the word "vainly" is not employing the same meaning as the idiom, "in vain".

OED defines *vain* as:

> Having or showing an excessively high opinion of one’s appearance, abilities, or worth:

Also consider the the suffix *-ly* as,

> an adjective suffix meaning “-like”: saintly; cowardly.

How the men win "the palm, the oaks, and the bays," is done in such a *vain-like* fashion that causes them to be amazed.

The use of 'vainly' in the peom, is essential in highlighting the hubristic nature of how men view their abilities; specifically the ones that allow them to achieve said prizes.

**Note:** [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Garden_%28poem%29) has some notes referring to author's use of 'vainly' to allude to *[vanitas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanitas)*.

**Edit:** I seemed to have tip-toed around your questions. For sake of clarity:

> 1.) Is the second one actually a different meaning or is it just a question of context?

The quote you provided, which I'm assuming is 'the second one', fits one of the definitions of vain, "having no success : not producing a desired result."

However, I do believe and as I attempted to explain above, that the word 'vain' isn't conveying this particular meaning.

> 2.) Are there any words which mean specifically the second?

For a list of synonyms, medica has provided an few words that can answer your that.

Comment: *Amaze* here is meant as *a maze* - to make crazy, to overwhelm; men overwhelm themselves **to no use, benefit, or advantage** in pursuing the palm (sainthood), the oak (conquering hero), the bay (poet/?art)... I don't think it's done from pride, but in vain.

Comment: @medica Ah, I see now. I probably should have looked deeper into the context of the poem. Thank you for pointing that out :)